# Framer motion new animation and exit not working with mapping

Tags: animation, next.js, framer-motion

for some reason my exit and new animation is not working. I would like new animation to start every time user click on different menu link. I have also tried with " animate='visible'" , and I have tried also to put  directly over motion, and it still not doing exit or starting new animation. I am using .map and framer motion together. Can someone please check it out.

This is the code

Thanks

```
const [forMapping, setForMapping] = useState(wines)

function menuHandler(index, alt) {
    setIsActive(index)
    if (alt === 'wine') {
        setForMapping(wines)
    } else if (alt === 'rakia') {
        setForMapping(rakia)
    }
}


    const variants = {
    visible: i => ({
        y: 0,
        transition: {
            duration: .7
        }
    }),
    hidden: {
        y: '40%'
    }
}


            <AnimatePresence>
                {forMapping.map((item, index) => {
                    const {
                        name,
                        description,
                        alt,
                        imageSrc,
                        price,
                        glass_price,
                        iconSrc,
                        alc
                    } = item;
                    return (
                        <motion.div
                            exit={{y: '100'}}
                            viewport={{once: true}}
                            custom={index}
                            whileInView='visible'
                            initial='hidden'
                            variants={variants}

                            key={index}
                            className='item'>
                            <div className="image">
                                <Image
                                    width={200}
                                    height={400}
                                    objectFit='cover'
                                    src={imageSrc}
                                    alt={alt}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="info">
                                <div className="info-header">
                                    <header>
                                        {name}
                                    </header>
                                    <p className="price">
                                        {price.toFixed(2)} EUR
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <p className="description">
                                    {description}
                                </p>
                                <div className="bottom">
                                    <p>
                                        {alc} %VOL
                                    </p>
                                    <div className='image-price'>
                                        <Image
                                            width={18}
                                            height={20}
                                            objectFit='cover'
                                            src={iconSrc}
                                            alt='wine glass'/>
                                        <p className="black">
                                            {glass_price.toFixed(2)} EUR
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </motion.div>
                    )
                })}
            </AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use the loop index as the `key` in your `motion.div`. Since the indices (and thus the keys) will always be the same, it doesn't let `<AnimatePresence>` track when elements have been added or removed in order to animate them.

Instead use a value like a unique `id` property for each element. This way React (and AnimatePresence) will know when it's rendering a different element (vs the same element with different data). This is what triggers the exit and enter animations.

Here's a more thorough explanation:
[react key props and why you shouldn’t be using index](https://stephenweiss.dev/react-key-props-and-why-you-shouldnt-be-using-index)

Comment: You were right. Working great now, and i understand now why. Thanks a lot man.